# PHP: Inserting data to another table

Tags: php

I have the function below that tells the database weather to update or insert dependent on if the email address has been found this works fine however I still have some `$POST` information that needs to go into another table dependent on the `id`

I have got it worked out that for the `if($emailCheck != FALSE)` statement I can run another `insert` statement and set the `id` within that

My question is how could I achieve this for the new `insert` of information in the `else` statement?

**Insert Function:**

```
function Insert()
{
  $emailCheck = $this->checkEmail($email);

  if($emailCheck != FALSE)
  {
    updateQuery by $emailCheck['id'])); // The email address is found so we update the data

  }else{

    Jojo::insertQuery; // The email address is not found so we insert the new row
  }
}
```

**Check Function:**

```
function checkEmail($email)
{
     $email = $POST['Email'];

    if($email)
    {
        $candemail = selectRow("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE email=?",$email);

        if(isset($candemail['email']))
        {
            return $candemail;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

**Full function:**

```
  function candidateInsert($fields, $candiatefilename,$jobid)
    {
      $emailCheck = Jojo_Plugin_name_jobs_apply::checkCandidateEmail($email);

      if($emailCheck != FALSE)
      {
        //Jojo::updateQuery("UPDATE {db} SET first_name=?,last_name=?,home_phone=?,work_phone=?,mobile_phone=?,email=?,skype=?,contact_method=?,location=?,location_other=?,cv_path=? WHERE id=?", array($fields['FirstName'],$fields['LastName'],$fields['HomePhone'],$fields['WorkPhone'],$fields['MobilePhone'],$fields['Email'],$fields['Skype'],$fields['ContactMethod'],$fields['Location'],$fields['LocationOther'],$candiatefilename, $emailCheck['id']));
        //Jojo::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {refocus_candidate_job} SET candidateID=?,jobID=?,appliedDate=?", array($emailCheck['id'],$jobid,date("d/m/y")));
    }else{
        Jojo::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {db} SET first_name=?,last_name=?,home_phone=?,work_phone=?,mobile_phone=?,email=?,skype=?,contact_method=?,location=?,location_other=?,cv_path=?", array($fields['FirstName'],$fields['LastName'],$fields['HomePhone'],$fields['WorkPhone'],$fields['MobilePhone'],$fields['Email'],$fields['Skype'],$fields['ContactMethod'],$fields['Location'],$fields['LocationOther'],$candiatefilename));

        $id = Jojo::insertQuery;

        //Jojo::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {db_candidate_job} SET candidateID=?,jobID=?,appliedDate=?", array($id,$jobid,date("d/m/y")));

        }
    }
```

Comment: what is exact problem? else statement doesn't execute ? if it execute correctly, then you can use $_POST in your function to build insert query.

Comment: @GBD I need to get the id of the fresh row that has been inserted via the else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute your code in following sequence in else statement.

First

```
$id = Jojo::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {db} SET first_name=?,last_name=?,home_phone=?,work_phone=?,mobile_phone=?,email=?,skype=?,contact_method=?,location=?,location_other=?,cv_path=?", array($fields['FirstName'],$fields['LastName'],$fields['HomePhone'],$fields['WorkPhone'],$fields['MobilePhone'],$fields['Email'],$fields['Skype'],$fields['ContactMethod'],$fields['Location'],$fields['LocationOther'],$candiatefilename));
```

Second

```
Jojo::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {db_candidate_job} SET candidateID=?,jobID=?,appliedDate=?", array($id,$jobid,date("d/m/y")));
```

Answer (score 1):

It says in the Jojo documentation. If you want to get the id of the freshly inserted row, just use

```
function Insert()
{
  $emailCheck = $this->checkEmail($email);

  if($emailCheck != FALSE)
  {
    updateQuery by $emailCheck['id'])); // The email address is found so we update the data
    $id = $emailCheck['id'];
  }else{

    $id = Jojo::insertQuery; // The email address is not found so we insert the new row
  }
  //at this point $id holds the id of the row.
}
```

then, after the if/else statement you can run the code on the second table, knowing you have the row's id, no matter which case(INSERT/UPDATE).

Comment: as per this http://www.jojocms.org/docs/database-queries/, you should get new row id. can you please paste full insert query ? it help us to debug more

Comment: @GBD done I am new to this and its confusing me

Comment: are you run insertQuery two times ? if yes, then run only this $id = Jojo::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {db} SET first_name=?,last_name=?,home_phone=?,work_phone=?,mobile_phone=?,email=?,skype=?,contact_method=?,location=?,location_other=?,cv_path=?", array($fields['FirstName'],$fields['LastName'],$fields['HomePhone'],$fields['WorkPhone'],$fields['MobilePhone'],$fields['Email'],$fields['Skype'],$fields['ContactMethod'],$fields['Location'],$fields['LocationOther'],$candiatefilename));

Comment: @GBD they are two different tables I somehow need to get the given id of the first insert to populate the 2nd

Comment: I mean to say run your code like this $id = Jojo::insertQuery(firsttable); Jojo::insertQuery(secondtable with $id value); is it help to you ?

Comment: @GBD You are the best :) Post and answer and thanks Vald